# How to change the default position of button tooltips in CKEditor 5

Tags: tooltip, ckeditor5

Having a small issue with tooltips in the editor, read the api but can't understand what it is saying and I can't seem to find examples anywhere that I can understand either.
I have set up a Classic Editor build, and all the buttons on the toolbar have tooltips with the default position below the button, I want to be able, just for this one instance of the editor, to change the tooltip position to above the buttons instead. The instance is set up like this:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#content' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
            this.annEditorInstance = editor;
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );
```

That creates an editor instance that is set up exactly as I want, except for the issue with the tooltip. How do I change this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to the problem:

#### CSS

Tooltips elements have either `.ck-tooltip_s` or `.ck-tooltip_n` class. By default all CKEditor 5 tooltips have the former so you could override it in your styles and make it act like the later:

```
<style>
    .ck.ck-tooltip.ck-tooltip_s {
        bottom: auto;
        top: calc(-1 * var(--ck-tooltip-arrow-size));
        transform: translateY( -100% );
    }

    .ck.ck-tooltip.ck-tooltip_s .ck-tooltip__text::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: calc(-1 * var(--ck-tooltip-arrow-size));
        transform: translateX( -50% );
        border-color: var(--ck-color-tooltip-background) transparent transparent transparent;
        border-width: var(--ck-tooltip-arrow-size) var(--ck-tooltip-arrow-size) 0 var(--ck-tooltip-arrow-size);
    }
</style>
```

#### JS

The [UI of the editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/ui-library.html) is an MVC(VM) structure. The position of the tooltip can be controlled using the JS and the [`Button#tooltipPosition`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_button-Button.html#member-tooltipPosition) property (`'s'` or `'n'`).

E.g. you can access the toolbar UI elements using `editor.ui.view.toolbar` and change their properties:

```
editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.map( item => item.tooltipPosition = 'n' )
```

but note that not all toolbar items are buttons. Some, for instance, are [dropdowns](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_dropdown_dropdownview-DropdownView.html) so you'd need to use `item.buttonView.tooltipPosition = 'n'` in that case. So unless you really want to use JS, I'd go with a simple CSS solution.

Comment: Thanks oleq, that really helped. Using:
`editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.map( item => item.tooltipPosition = 'n' )`
worked in the way you said, and also as you said, the dropdown buttons were not changed and needed their own fix.
At first I tried this:
`editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.map( item => item.buttonView.tooltipPosition = 'n' )`
but it did not work, as not all the items in the map have buttonViews, just the dropdowns.

Comment: So for the dropdowns, I ended up with this as a working solution:
`var itemButtonView = editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.filter(item => item.buttonView);
for(var i = 0; i < itemButtonView.length; i++){
 itemButtonView[i].buttonView.tooltipPosition = 'n';}`

Comment: So everything works. If there is a better way, I would still be interested in hearing about it.